# Alternative to one-sample t-test when data is not normal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

I have a variable whose values range between 1 for strongly disagree and 5 strongly agree. I want to test the hypothesis if the respondents (managers) agree on the new implemented procedure. So I want to check if the mean is 3.5, but the data is not normal so I cannot use a one-sample t-test. What can I use in this case?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to check if the mean is 3.5? It isn't obvious to me what is so special about the figure 3.5 and why this should form your null hypothesis. I think it would also be a good idea to specify your alternative hypothesis.

Comment: Your scale is ordinal. What does an average of 3.5 mean in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Since the data is ordinal (not continuous) and does not follow a Normal distribution, I recommend using a Wilcoxon Rank Sum test (aka Mann–Whitney U test) instead of a t-test. Wilcoxon Rank Sum test is a nonparametric approach to the t-test.

You can find more information about the assumptions here:
https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/mann-whitney-u-test-using-spss-statistics.php

In R, you can implement the test with the following commands. Example:

```
> fake_data <- rpois(n = 100, lambda = 5)
> wilcox.test(x = fake_data, mu = 3.5)

Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  fake_data
V = 3986, p-value = 4.204e-07
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 3.5

## reject H_0: true location is equal to 3.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. i understood the Mann Whitney test, but then i have to have 2 groups, which i don't. So is this the only way to see if the whole sample agree on the new implemented program or its a must to split the sample into 2 groups in order to use Mann Whitney test? thank you again

Comment: No, you do not need two samples. If you only have 1 sample, that would be your data, and you would simply state your null hypothesis with the variable 'mu'. In the code I chose mu = 3.5, just like you were interested in. However, there were other respondents who asked this, why 3.5? Is 3.5 directly interpretable for your ordinal data? I suggest really thinking through about what your null and alternative hypotheses should be before continuing with the analysis. Else, you risk continuing with a poor analysis, and nobody wants that.